# Reset state of jQuery plugin Remodal on page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, remodal

I am using the jQuery plugin [Remodal](https://github.com/VodkaBears/Remodal#remodal) to create a modal for my website. I am following the documentation on their website however I am running into an issue with opening and closing the modal. If I open the modal then refresh my browser the next time the page loads the modal will still be open. I created an instance of the modal using `var inst = $('[data-remodal-id=modal]').remodal();` and did a `console.log(inst.getState());` and the modal was stuck in in the "opening" state. I also tried to run the `inst.close();` function but that didnt work as well.

Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var inst = $('[data-remodal-id=modal]').remodal();
  console.log(inst.getState()); //if I refresh with the modal open this will print "opening".
  //I want the modal to be closed every time the page is refreshed
  $('#div').click(function() {
     inst.open();
  });
  $(document).on('opening', '.remodal', function () {
    //when the modal opens open another jQuery plugin
    $("#gallery").unitegallery();
  });
});
```

Within my html body I have the following code:

```
<div data-remodal-id="modal"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and solved it by setting the option `hashTracking` to `false`.

This can be done in the HTML directly, by setting `data-remodal-option="hashTracking: false"`, or by specifying it with the `options` parameter when constructing the Remodal from code. See also [the Remodal docs on options](https://github.com/VodkaBears/Remodal#options).